# Is 2-bromo-3-methylbutane chiral?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

Is 2-bromo-3-methylbutane chiral?

[image: 2-bromo-3-methylbutane]

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what the molecule is from your diagram, but in your first comment you state "It is a ethane (2 carbons) with 3 methyls on the 1st carbon, and a bromine and a methyl on the 2nd carbon"

If you draw out the structure you describe above I see four consecutive carbons. Since one of the methyls attached to the "1st carbon" makes the main chain longer and the methyl adjacent to the bromine on the "2nd carbon" also makes the chain longer. Thus, you have a butane as the main chain.

You have two constituents remaining the bromine on carbon 2 and the di-methyls on carbon 3. The name is thus 2-bromo-3,3-dimethylbutane

Also the molecule is chiral since the bromine makes the molecule nonsuperimposable.